# Related to building interface using python Tkinter module

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, interface

The main code should have a simple interface through which it should get called and we need to get the results.

For example, we have a python code which prints the log analysis when we give zip file input. Now we need to build an interface and include the python code in there.

I have tried writing the code using Tkinter module as below.

```
from tkinter import *

  # create root window 
root = Tk()

  # root window title and dimension 
root.title("Welcome to Auto Triage")  

# Set geometry (widthxheight) 
root.geometry('350x200')

  # adding a label to the root window 
lbl = Label(root, text="Trigger Auto Triage Tool")
 lbl.grid()

   # function to display text when button is clicked
 f = open('runAUTOTriage.py','r') 
temp = f.read() 
f.close()

 def clicked():     
   lbl.configure(compile(temp,'runAUTOTriage.py','exec'))   

# button widget with red color text inside 
btn = Button(root, text="Click Me", fg="black", command=clicked) 

# set Button grid
 btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

  root.mainloop()
```

After executing the code, it is giving below error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\asamudrx\OneDrive - Intel Corporation\Desktop\Auto Triage\GUI_Auto_Triage\gui_auto_triage.py", line 23, in clicked
    lbl.configure(compile(temp,r'C:\Users\asamudrx\OneDrive - Intel Corporation\Desktop\Auto_Triage_Apurva\Auto_Triage_v20811\runAUTOTriage.py','exec'))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1660, in _configure
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 109, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
TypeError: object of type 'code' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Whatever this line of code `lbl.configure(compile(temp,'runAUTOTriage.py','exec'))   ` is supposed to do, it does not configure the label with a valid *optional argument* and a *appropriated value*.

Comment: I would like to execute the code (runAUTOTriage.py) and get the output.